# Rake::TestTask test_files vs. pattern

Tags: ruby, rake

Is there any advantage of using `pattern` over `test_files`?

It seems like they do the same thing:

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  # t.pattern = FileList['test/test_*.rb', 'test/*_test.rb']
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb', 'test/*_test.rb']
end
```

Also, looking over the [source](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/34a2353ac5cfe315dbc12ab17ece22b672b2740c/lib/rake/testtask.rb#L84-L103) for `Rake::TestTask#initialize` I couldn't tell the difference either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test_files` expects an array of filenames, FileList can be used, it is kind of an explicit listing of files

`pattern` expects a glob pattern, a string

If both is set, the actual list will be the union of the two. There is not really a difference between them.